# Did someone give a try the Http Live Streaming in Android V3.0?

Tags: android

As you should know, Google annonced that Apple Http Live Streaming is now supported in the SDK V3.0 via the mediaPlayer Framework.

So I wrote some lines to test this. I started with a "3gp" movie that is correclty displayed on the emulator (a tablet). When I feed the source with a working m3u8 URL nothing is displayed and the debugger reports an error

Can someone lead me from darkness to light ???

I guess it has something to do with codec but...

Many thanks for any clue.
Zbb

```
02-15 09:49:31.284: INFO/avc_utils(33): found AVC codec config (320 x 180, Main-profile level 1.3)
02-15 09:49:31.444: INFO/ESQueue(33): found AAC codec config (24000 Hz, 2 channels)
02-15 09:49:31.444: INFO/ESQueue(33): [ 02-15 09:49:31.454    33:0x1b9 F/ACodec   ]
02-15 09:49:31.444: INFO/ESQueue(33): frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:1594 
CHECK_EQ( omx->allocateNode(componentName.c_str(), observer, &node),(status_t)OK) failed: -2147483648 vs. 0
02-15 09:49:31.605: INFO/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-15 09:49:31.605: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:Honeycomb/HPI20B/eng.xav.20110125.162619:eng/test-keys'
02-15 09:49:31.605: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 33, tid: 441  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
02-15 09:49:31.615: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
```